# C3.js and JavaScript - How to integrate buttons with the legend of the chart

Tags: javascript, html, c3.js

I am working with a c3.js chart and want to integrate buttons with the legend of the chart. I know that this is possible using JavaScript, but I don't know how to relate the button in the HTML page with the elements in the c3.js code.

My code is this:

```js
  /* set the default locale to pt-br */
    d3.timeFormatDefaultLocale({
      "decimal": ",",
      "thousands": ".",
      "grouping": [3],
      "currency": ["R$", ""],
      "dateTime": "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
      "date": "%d/%m/%Y",
      "time": "%H:%M:%S",
      "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
      "days": ["Domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"],
      "shortDays": ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"],
      "months": ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
      "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"]
    });

    var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: {
        x: 'x',
        // xFormat: '%Y%m%d', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
        columns: [
          [
            'x',
            '2022-03-04',
            '2022-03-05',
            '2022-03-06',
            '2022-03-07',
            '2022-03-08',
            '2022-03-09',
            '2022-03-10',
            '2022-03-11',
            '2022-03-12',
            '2022-03-13',
            '2022-03-14',
            '2022-03-15',
            '2022-03-16',
            '2022-03-17',
            '2022-03-18',
            '2022-03-19',
            '2022-03-20',
            '2022-03-21',
            '2022-03-22',
            '2022-03-23',
            '2022-03-24',
            '2022-03-25',
            '2022-03-26',
            '2022-03-27',
            '2022-03-28',
            '2022-03-29',
            '2022-03-30',
            '2022-03-31',
            '2022-04-01',
            '2022-04-02',
            '2022-04-03',
            '2022-04-04',
            '2022-04-05',
            '2022-04-06',
            '2022-04-07',
            '2022-04-08',
            '2022-04-09',
            '2022-04-10',
            '2022-04-11',
            '2022-04-12',
            '2022-04-13',
            '2022-04-14',
            '2022-04-15',
            '2022-04-16',
            '2022-04-17',
            '2022-04-18',
            '2022-04-19',
            '2022-04-20',
            '2022-04-21',
            '2022-04-22',
            '2022-04-23',
            '2022-04-24',
            '2022-04-25',
            '2022-04-26',
            '2022-04-27',
            '2022-04-28',
            '2022-04-29',
            '2022-04-30',
            '2022-05-01',
            '2022-05-02',
            '2022-05-03',
            '2022-05-04',
            '2022-05-05',
            '2022-05-06',
            '2022-05-07',
            '2022-05-08',
            '2022-05-09',
            '2022-05-10',
            '2022-05-11',
            '2022-05-12',
            '2022-05-13',
            '2022-05-14',
            '2022-05-15'
          ],
          [
            'A',
            43,
            42.978,
            42.956,
            42.933,
            42.911,
            42.889,
            42.867,
            42.844,
            42.822,
            42.8,
            42.778,
            42.756,
            42.733,
            42.711,
            42.689,
            42.667,
            42.644,
            42.622,
            42.6,
            42.578,
            42.556,
            42.533,
            42.511,
            42.489,
            42.467,
            42.444,
            42.422,
            42.4,
            42.378,
            42.356,
            42.333,
            42.311,
            42.289,
            42.267,
            42.244,
            42.222,
            42.2,
            42.178,
            42.156,
            42.133,
            42.111,
            42.089,
            42.067,
            42.044,
            42.022,
            42.0,
            42,
            41.5,
            41.0,
            40.5,
            40.0,
            39.5,
            39.0,
            38.5,
            38.0,
            38,
            38.75,
            39.5,
            40.25,
            41.0,
            41,
            40.857,
            40.714,
            40.571,
            40.429,
            40.286,
            40.143,
            40.0,
            40,
            40.0,
            40.0,
            40.0,
            40
          ],
          [
            'B',
            28,
            27.978,
            27.956,
            27,
            27.933,
            27.911,
            27.889,
            27.867,
            27.844,
            27.822,
            27.8,
            27.778,
            27.756,
            27.733,
            27.711,
            27.689,
            27.667,
            27.644,
            27.622,
            27.6,
            27.578,
            27.556,
            27.533,
            27.511,
            27.489,
            27.467,
            27.444,
            27.422,
            27.4,
            27.378,
            27.356,
            27.333,
            27.311,
            27.289,
            27.267,
            27.244,
            27.222,
            27.2,
            27.178,
            27.156,
            27.133,
            27.111,
            27.089,
            27.067,
            27.044,
            27.022,
            27.0,
            27,
            27.5,
            28.0,
            28.5,
            29.0,
            29.5,
            30.0,
            30.5,
            31.0,
            31,
            30.25,
            29.5,
            28.75,
            28.0,
            28,
            28.286,
            28.571,
            28.857,
            29.143,
            29.429,
            29.714,
            30.0,
            30,
            29.667,
            29.333,
            29.0,
            29
          ],
          [
            'C',
            6,
            6.022,
            6.044,
            6.067,
            6.089,
            6.111,
            6.133,
            6.156,
            6.178,
            6.2,
            6.222,
            6.244,
            6.267,
            6.289,
            6.311,
            6.333,
            6.356,
            6.378,
            6.4,
            6.422,
            6.444,
            6.467,
            6.489,
            6.511,
            6.533,
            6.556,
            6.578,
            6.6,
            6.622,
            6.644,
            6.667,
            6.689,
            6.711,
            6.733,
            6.756,
            6.778,
            6.8,
            6.822,
            6.844,
            6.867,
            6.889,
            6.911,
            6.933,
            6.956,
            6.978,
            7.0,
            7,
            7.0,
            7.0,
            7.0,
            7.0,
            7.0,
            7.0,
            7.0,
            7.0,
            7,
            7.75,
            8.5,
            9.25,
            10.0,
            10,
            9.571,
            9.143,
            8.714,
            8.286,
            7.857,
            7.429,
            7.0,
            7,
            7.333,
            7.667,
            8.0,
            8
          ],
          [
            'D',
            3,
            3.044,
            3.089,
            3.133,
            3.178,
            3.222,
            3.267,
            3.311,
            3.356,
            3.4,
            3.444,
            3.489,
            3.533,
            3.578,
            3.622,
            3.667,
            3.711,
            3.756,
            3.8,
            3.844,
            3.889,
            3.933,
            3.978,
            4.022,
            4.067,
            4.111,
            4.156,
            4.2,
            4.244,
            4.289,
            4.333,
            4.378,
            4.422,
            4.467,
            4.511,
            4.556,
            4.6,
            4.644,
            4.689,
            4.733,
            4.778,
            4.822,
            4.867,
            4.911,
            4.956,
            5.0,
            5,
            4.225,
            4.25,
            3.875,
            3.5,
            3.125,
            2.75,
            2.375,
            2.0,
            2,
            2.5,
            3.0,
            3.5,
            4.0,
            4,
            4.143,
            4.286,
            4.429,
            4.571,
            4.714,
            4.857,
            5.0,
            5,
            4.333,
            3.667,
            3.0,
            3
          ],
          [
            'E',
            4,
            3.978,
            3.956,
            3.933,
            3.911,
            3.889,
            3.867,
            3.844,
            3.822,
            3.8,
            3.778,
            3.756,
            3.733,
            3.711,
            3.689,
            3.667,
            3.644,
            3.622,
            3.6,
            3.578,
            3.556,
            3.533,
            3.511,
            3.489,
            3.467,
            3.444,
            3.422,
            3.4,
            3.378,
            3.356,
            3.333,
            3.311,
            3.289,
            3.267,
            3.244,
            3.222,
            3.2,
            3.178,
            3.156,
            3.133,
            3.111,
            3.089,
            3.067,
            3.044,
            3.022,
            3.0,
            3,
            2.75,
            2.5,
            2.25,
            2.0,
            1.75,
            1.5,
            1.25,
            1.0,
            1,
            1.5,
            2.0,
            2.5,
            3.0,
            3,
            2.857,
            2.714,
            2.571,
            2.429,
            2.286,
            2.143,
            2.0,
            2,
            2.0,
            2.0,
            2.0,
            2
          ],
          [
            'F',
            16,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16.0,
            16,
            16.625,
            17.25,
            17.875,
            18.5,
            19.125,
            19.75,
            20.375,
            21.0,
            21,
            19.25,
            17.5,
            15.75,
            14.0,
            14,
            14.286,
            14.571,
            14.857,
            15.143,
            15.429,
            15.714,
            16.0,
            16,
            16.667,
            17.333,
            18.0,
            18
          ]
        ],
        colors: {
          A: '#6973ad',
          B: '#fd6166',
          C: '#c05b5e',
          D: '#fece43',
          E: '#78D2D7',
          F: '#000000'
        }
      },
      axis: {
        x: {
          type: 'timeseries',
          tick: {
            format: d3.timeFormat('%d/%b'),
            values: ['2022-03-05', '2022-03-15', '2022-03-30', '2022-04-15', '2022-04-30', '2022-05-10'],
            outer: false
          }
        },
        y: {
          padding: {
            bottom: 11
          },
          tick: {
            count: 4,
            values: [0, 15, 30, 45]
          }
        }
      },
      size: {
        width: 700,
        height: 500
      },
      grid: {
        y: {
          show: true
        }
      }
    })
```

```css
  /*buttons*/
  .title-media {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Sentinel SSm A", "Sentinel SSm B", "Sentinel SSm", serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    justify-content: left;
    width: 752px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 50px auto auto;
    padding-bottom: 19px;
  }

  .button-wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .button-candidatos {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .cyrcle-phto {
    min-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }

  .photo-candidato {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }

  .name-candidato {
    font: 12px "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
  }

  .sigla-partido {
    font: 12px "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .img-ponteiro {
    width: 25px;
    height: 33px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 11px;
  }

  .text-ponteiro {
    font: 12px "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
    width: 45%;
  }

  .legenda {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .legenda-texto {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    font: 12px "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
    width: 752px;
    height: auto;
  }

  /*buttons*/
  .c3 svg {
    font: 10px "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  }

  #chart {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .c3 line,
  .c3 path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #EEEEEE;
    /*esse elemento define a linha dos eixos x e y*/
  }

  .c3 .c3-axis-x path {
    stroke: #484848;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  /*alteração do estilo do tooltip*/
  #chart .c3-tooltip th {
    font-family: "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }

  #chart .c3-tooltip td {
    font-family: "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
  }

  /*alteração do estilo do tooltip*/
  .c3 .c3-axis-x line {
    stroke: transparent;
    fill: none;
  }

  g .tick {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .c3 text {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font: 12px "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
  }

  .c3-bars path,
  .c3-event-rect,
  .c3-legend-item-tile,
  .c3-xgrid-focus,
  .c3-ygrid {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges
  }

  .c3-chart-arc path {
    stroke: #fff
  }

  .c3-chart-arc rect {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1
  }

  .c3-chart-arc text {
    fill: #fff;
    font-size: 13px
  }

  .c3-grid line {
    stroke: #aaa;
  }

  .c3-grid text {
    fill: #aaa
  }

  .c3-xgrid,
  .c3-ygrid {
    stroke-dasharray: 3 3
  }

  .c3-text.c3-empty {
    fill: grey;
    font-size: 2em
  }

  .c3-line {
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .c3-circle {
    fill: transparent;
  }

  .c3-circle._expanded_ {
    stroke-width: 3px;
    fill: white;
    stroke: currentColor;
  }

  .c3-selected-circle {
    fill: white;
    stroke: currentColor;
    stroke-width: 2px
  }

  .c3-bar {
    stroke-width: 0
  }

  .c3-bar._expanded_ {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    fill-opacity: .75
  }

  .c3-target.c3-focused {
    opacity: 1
  }

  .c3-target.c3-focused path.c3-line,
  .c3-target.c3-focused path.c3-step {
    stroke-width: 2px
  }

  .c3-target.c3-defocused {
    opacity: .3 !important
  }

  .c3-region {
    fill: #4682b4;
    fill-opacity: .1
  }

  .c3-region text {
    fill-opacity: 1
  }

  .c3-brush .extent {
    fill-opacity: .1
  }

  .c3-legend-item {
    font: 14px "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
  }

  tspan {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Gotham Rounded SSm A", "Gotham Rounded SSm B", sans-serif;
  }

  .tick {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .c3-legend-item-hidden {
    opacity: .15
  }

  .c3-legend-background {
    opacity: .75;
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #d3d3d3;
    stroke-width: 1
  }

  .c3-title {
    font: 14px sans-serif
  }

  .c3-tooltip-container {
    z-index: 10
  }

  .c3-tooltip {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    empty-cells: show;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 12px -9px #777;
    opacity: .9
  }

  .c3-tooltip tr {
    border: 1px solid #ccc
  }

  .c3-tooltip th {
    background-color: #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff
  }

  .c3-tooltip td {
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px dotted #999
  }

  .c3-tooltip td>span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 6px
  }

  .c3-tooltip .value {
    text-align: right
  }

  .c3-area {
    stroke-width: 0;
    opacity: .2
  }

  .c3-chart-arcs-title {
    dominant-baseline: middle;
    font-size: 1.3em
  }

  .c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-background {
    fill: #e0e0e0;
    stroke: #fff
  }

  .c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-unit {
    fill: #000;
    font-size: 16px
  }

  .c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-max {
    fill: #777
  }

  .c3-chart-arcs .c3-chart-arcs-gauge-min {
    fill: #777
  }

  .c3-chart-arc .c3-gauge-value {
    fill: #000
  }

  .c3-chart-arc.c3-target g path {
    opacity: 1
  }

  .c3-chart-arc.c3-target.c3-focused g path {
    opacity: 1
  }

  .c3-drag-zoom.enabled {
    pointer-events: all !important;
    visibility: visible
  }

  .c3-drag-zoom.disabled {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    visibility: hidden
  }

  .c3-drag-zoom .extent {
    fill-opacity: .1
  }

  #chart .c3-line-Lula,
  .c3-line-Bolsonaro,
  .c3-line-Janones,
  .c3-line-Ciro,
  .c3-line-Tebet,
  .c3-line-BNI,
  .c3-line-Outros {
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }

  p.intencao {
    font-family: 'Gotham Rounded SSm A', 'Gotham Rounded SSm B', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #111111;
    margin: 40px 18px 0 -20px;
  }

  #chart,
  svg {
    width: 750;
    height: 515;
    margin-left: -49px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    #chart {
      margin-left: -172px;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    #chart,
    svg {
      width: 750;
      height: 515;
    }

    .container {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 750px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width:376px) {
    .button-candidatos {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .cyrcle-phto {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
    }

    .img-ponteiro {
      margin-left: 58px;
      margin-top: 16px;
    }

    .text-ponteiro {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 375px) and (min-width:321px) {
    .button-candidatos {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .cyrcle-phto {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
    }

    .img-ponteiro {
      margin-left: 58px;
      margin-top: 16px;
    }

    .text-ponteiro {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .button-candidatos {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .cyrcle-phto {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
    }

    .img-ponteiro {
      margin-left: 58px;
      margin-top: 16px;
    }

    .text-ponteiro {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="button-wrap">
  </div>
  <div class="button-candidatos">
    <div class="cyrcle-phto col-xs-4 col-md-1" id="A-btn">
      <div><img class="img-circle photo-candidato" src="https://assets.shared.cloud.nexojornal.com.br/graficos/2022/08/01/BNI.png"></div>
      <div><span class="name-candidato">A<br></span></span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cyrcle-phto col-xs-4 col-md-1" id="B-btn">
      <div><img class="img-circle photo-candidato" src="https://assets.shared.cloud.nexojornal.com.br/graficos/2022/08/01/BNI.png"></div>
      <div><span class="name-candidato">B</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cyrcle-phto col-xs-4 col-md-1" id="C-btn">
      <div><img class="img-circle photo-candidato" src="https://assets.shared.cloud.nexojornal.com.br/graficos/2022/08/01/BNI.png"></div>
      <div><span class="name-candidato">C</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cyrcle-phto col-xs-4 col-md-1" id="D-btn">
      <div><img class="img-circle photo-candidato" src="https://assets.shared.cloud.nexojornal.com.br/graficos/2022/08/01/BNI.png"></div>
      <div><span class="name-candidato">D</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cyrcle-phto col-xs-4 col-md-1" id="E-btn">
      <div><img class="img-circle photo-candidato" src="https://assets.shared.cloud.nexojornal.com.br/graficos/2022/08/01/BNI.png"></div>
      <div><span class="name-candidato">E</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="cyrcle-phto col-xs-4 col-md-1" id="F-btn">
      <div><img class="img-circle photo-candidato" src="https://assets.shared.cloud.nexojornal.com.br/graficos/2022/08/01/BNI.png"></div>
      <div><span class="name-candidato">F</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://central-de-pesquisa-2022.s3.amazonaws.com/c3.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Load d3-time-format -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-time-format@4"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

For example, I would like to click on the button with `id=A-btn` and trigger off the same event when I click the button A `class="c3-legend-item c3-legend-item-A"` in the legend of the chart. I.e. click on the button and remove/replace the line on the chart.

Can someone help me? Thanks! :)

Comment: i'm assuming the first code is the javascript c3.js code, please confirm

Comment: @iamdeed hi, thank you for your response! yes, it is javascript c3.js code